# How to get the length of map of Json in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on improving a quiz app.
I get the data from Json file into my project as mydata.

```
class quizpage extends StatefulWidget {
  var mydata;

  quizpage({Key key, @required this.mydata}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _quizpageState createState() => _quizpageState(mydata);
}

class _quizpageState extends State<quizpage> {
  final mydata;
  _quizpageState(this.mydata);
```

I want to find the length of the elements inside my son file.
This is the demo data inside Json file.

```
[
    {
        "1": "What's your name?",
        "2": "Which function finds out the Variable type in Python ?",
        "3": "Which of the following keyword is used to define a function ",

    },
    {
        "1": {
            "a": "mon",
            "b": "monmon",
            "c": "monmonmon",
            "d": "monmonmon"
        },
        "2": {
            "a": "monmon",
            "b": "mon",
            "c": "monmonmon",
            "d": "monmonmon"
        },
        "3": {
            "a": "monmonmon",
            "b": "monmon",
            "c": "mon",
            "d": "monmonmon"
        },

    },
    {
        "1": "mon",
        "2": "mon",
        "3": "mon",

    }

]
```

I want to check the length of the Json map
When I press. after mydata[0].   it doesn't show me length.

```
void nextquestion() {
    setState(() {
      if (i < mydata[0].length) {

        i++;
      }
```

Here it throws an error `(i < mydata[0].length)` 
What should I do?

Comment: .length is spelt wrong.

Comment: [edit] the error message into the question please.

Comment: Thanks. In the editor when I press dot after                        mydata[0].        it doesn't give me (length) at all.

Comment: @MontasserMohamed Then what does `print("${mydata[0].runtimeType}")` print?

Comment: @MontasserMohamed it is properly because the list is the type of `List<dynamic>` which means Dart don't know what the list contains. So `mydata[0]` returns `dynamic` so Dart cannot give you any auto completion.

Comment: @julemand101 So how can I define it as a string

Comment: The simplest way is to make a type cast like `(mydata[0] as String).length` if you are only using the data a few places. But the best solution would be to make your code type safe and convert your `List<dynamic>` to `List<String>` with: `mydata.cast<String>()`.

Comment: Seems you have an excessive  comma at end of line 4. Maybe your json is not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign your variable to the type you want to use.

```
(mydata[0] as Map<String, dynamic>).length
```